# Python multiprocessing.Pool: Why doesn't adding additional processes seem to improve performance on a hyperthreaded system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, hyperthreading

I'm experimenting with Python 3's multiprocessing module, and have the following code that reads a file containing a number on each line and prints the factorization of each number:

```
import multiprocessing
import sys

NUM_PROCESSES = 4
CHUNK_SIZE = 20

def factor(n):
    #Return a list of factors of n
    factors = []
    #factor out 2's
    while n % 2 == 0:
        factors.append(2)
        n //= 2
    factor = 3
    while n > 1:
        if n % factor == 0:
            factors.append(factor)
            n //= factor
        else:
            factor += 2
    return factors

def process_line(line):
    #process an input file line
    number = int(line)
    factorization = '*'.join(str(x) for x in factor(number))
    return f'{number} = {factorization}\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        with multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES) as pool:
            processed = pool.imap(process_line, f, CHUNK_SIZE)
            sys.stdout.writelines(processed)
```

I am running this on a Linux system with 2 hyperthreaded physical cores, for a total of 4 virtual cores. I tested this script on a file containing 10,000 random numbers between 2 and 1,000,000, and measured its performance with the `time` command.

When `NUM_PROCESSES` is 1, I get the result:

```
real    0m26.997s
user    0m26.979s
sys     0m0.077s
```

When `NUM_PROCESSES` is 2, I get:

```
real    0m13.477s
user    0m26.809s
sys     0m0.048s
```

So far this is what I'd expect - adding another process cuts the run time almost exactly in half while the total CPU time remains the same. But when `NUM_PROCESSES` is 4, I get:

```
real    0m14.598s
user    0m56.703s
sys     0m0.059s
```

Not only did the run time not decrease, but it increased by 1 second, even though the CPU time has doubled. This basically means that each virtual CPU was running at half the speed of a physical CPU, so there was no performance benefit from running on all 4 virtual CPUs. Changing `CHUNK_SIZE` does not seem to significantly affect the performance, event if I set it to 1 or 2,500. Using `map()` instead of `imap()` also doesn't change anything.

From my understanding, virtual hyperthreaded cores do not offer the same performance benefits as additional physical cores, but they should still offer *some* improvement, right? Why then did the script's performance not improve?

Comment: You need to leave at least one thread for the system to run. So try with NUM_PROCESSES = 3.

Comment: This article may appear to be interesting, it explains many things: https://medium.com/@bfortuner/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-73072ce5600b

Comment: If I use 3 processes I get real 0m13.809s, user 0m41.019s, so still no improvement.
The task I am running _is_ CPU intensive, it performs no IO at all. So this is why I figure that more processes should mean better performance.

Comment: Hyperthreading only adds something like 20-30% performance on a good day. For some workloads the performance benefit of hyperthreading is zero or negative.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry i cant add a comment yet) Can you show the output of lscpu ? Creating too many processes/threads will cause [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). When you run this and use htop, are all cores 100%?